# Recent reputation calculation bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, users, reputation

Not a big deal, it just displays wrong from time to time as seen in the picture:

[image: 58 should be 59]

It should be 59, but shows 58.

**Update:**
Perhaps this is my mistake, looking back now I see there was another downvote between the WOL and PHP questions (two downvotes in a row). I assumed that these 5 were the most recent 5, but apparently that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually click on the reputation tab dou see something different?  Did you perhaps downvote another question that isn't listed because it is not the 'Top 5' view you are currently looking at?

Comment: Perhaps this is my mistake, looking back now I see there was another downvote between the WOL and PHP questions (two downvotes in a row). I assumed that these 5 were the most recent 5, but apparently that is not the case??